# Displaying information from Redux store using Array.prototype.find() causes error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am building an app which retrieves blog post data from an API. This data is an array of objects. Each object has a unique key called `nid`. I need to get the correct object based on the `nid` when a user selects a blog post to read. Attempting to use `Array.prototype.find()` method on the array from my redux store throws error when used in my `BlogDetail.js` component.

I've tested using this method in `componentDidMount()`, as well as within the `render()` method itself. Both will work on some occasions, and fail with an error other times with no changes made in between. I have also logged `Array.isArray(posts)` to ensure that this is indeed an array and that has returned `true`. I have also been able to confirm using the Redux DevTools that the `state.content.blog.posts` entry is populated with data at the time that this component loads. Finally, I have tried other Array methods on the `posts` array and they have yielded the same result.

My Component BlogDetail.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class BlogDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation, posts } = this.props;
        let post = posts.find(el => el.nid === navigation.getParam("nid"));
        let BlogImage;
        if (post.large_image && post.large_image !== '') {
            BlogImage = <Image style={{ width: 500, height: 300, resizeMode: 'cover' }} source={{ uri: post.large_image }} />;
        }
        return (
            <View>
                {BlogImage}
                <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
                    <Text>{post.title}</Text>
                    // Some logic which needs the post ...
                </View>
            </View >
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.content.blog.posts
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(BlogDetail);
```

Example of `state.content.blog.posts` array:

```
[
  {
    nid: 123, 
    title: "A blog post", 
    body: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 
    large_image: "http://something.com/image",
  }, 
  {
    nid: 234, 
    title: "Another Blog Post", 
    body: "Lorem ipsum something something", 
    large_image: "http://something.com/image2"
  }
]
```

I would expect that this would filter the array `state.content.blog.posts` and display the information for the particular post that I need to show. However I get the following error, inconsistently, when the component loads:

`TypeError: posts.find() is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, when the render function called the `posts` is not an array. We can prevent the situation by adding default value like,

`const { navigation, posts = [] } = this.props;`

or in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here,

**Issue 1**

```
const { navigation, posts } = this.props;
let post = posts.find(el => el.nid === navigation.getParam("nid")); //TypeError: posts.find() is not a function
```

Solution to this is,

[Destructuring Assignment with Default Values](https://zaiste.net/javascript_destructuring_assignment_default_values/) like,

```
const { navigation, posts = []} = this.props;
let post = posts.find(el => el.nid === navigation.getParam("nid"));
```

Another solution is, checking if `this.props` contains data,

```
const { navigation, posts } = this.props;
let post = this.props.posts ? posts.find(el => el.nid === navigation.getParam("nid")) : [];
```

**Issue 2**

You are exporting your component at two places,

```
export class BlogDetail extends Component {...}
```

And

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(BlogDetail);
```

If not necessary, remove export from class declaration, like you should only have,

```
class BlogDetail extends Component {...}
```

Comment: The reason for Issue 2 is because I wanted to test the component without redux, the easiest way I found to do that was just to export the `connect()` as default and export the component itself as `{ BlogDetail }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign destructured values default values

```
const { navigation, posts = [] } = this.props; 
let post = posts.find(el => el.nid === navigation.getParam("nid")); 
if (!post) { 
    return;
} 
let BlogImage;
```